# Bootstrap Jquery <li> on click add icon to list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a unordered expandable bootsrap list.

When a user selects one of the items on the list (for example Day) i want to show an icon on the right.

currently i am using bootsrap hidden class to hide the span on the list. When the user selects the option i want the icon to appear so that it looks selected.

I have made  [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/1FOaH63cC5)

Is there a better way to do this than having all the icons on the list as hidden? Currently my Jquery function is not working:

**JQUERY**

```
$('ul.list-group li').click(function(e) 
{ 
    $('li.list-group-item').removeClass('list-group-item');
});
```

**CSS**

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Monday <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Tuesday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Wednesday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Thursday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Friday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Saturday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Sunday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span></li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: you could use .append and .remove to add and remove the icons (the `<i>` elements with some extra class or something to identify them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is just `toggle` the `hidden` class from the `span` element when clicking `li.list-group-item`

```
$('li.list-group-item').click(function(e) {
    $(this).children('span').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```js
$('li.list-group-item').click(function(e) {
  $(this).children('span').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Monday <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Tuesday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Wednesday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Thursday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Friday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Saturday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Sunday<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right hidden"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$('.list-group-item').click(function() { 
    $(this).children('span').toggleClass('hidden');   
});
```

What this will do is toggle the hidden class when when you click a list item. However, it still requires the hidden class.

What you could do is, in your css, something like this:

```
.list-group-item span {
    display: none;
}

.list-group-item.active span {
    display: block;
}
```

And then in your javascript you could do this:

```
$('.list-group-item').click(function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass('active');   
});
```

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could be of service! If it ends up doing what you're after then please mark it as the correct answer :)

If not then don't hesitate to ask for more help!

Comment: unfortunately this does not make the tick icon appear but it makes the <li> highlighted when its clicked..

Comment: Did you remove the class of hidden from all the `<span>`s in your markup? Also, are you using my second answer that requires modifying both your CSS and JS?

Comment: Hi, i did remove the class hidden from all the spans and i added the css. Im using the second answer css and js change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134776/discussion-between-bert-and-user1673498).